# Modelo de reconocimiento de productos

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

¡Buenas!

Estoy tratando de implementar una funcionalidad en un sistema que estoy desarrollando.
El sistema estaría enfocado a la venta de suministros a distintas empresas (un usuario contactaría con esta empresa, y le enviaría un texto, a modo de solicitud).

El texto de la solicitud del cliente podría tener la siguiente estructura:

```
solicitud = """Buenas! Necesito que me envieis 2 bateiras. 
               Por otro lado, ultimanente echamos en falta algunas unidades de leids, unas 3.
               También estaría bien 1 actavox. Gracias!
               
               Se me olvidaba añadir los siguientes productos: 
                 - Me han pedido que incluya en la compra 4 transnistores.
                 - Estamos bajos en stock de fulsilbes, por lo que no nos vendría mal 10 unidades.
                 - A partir de dentro de unas cuantas semanas, preveemos una maoyr venta de interrutroes."""
```

Se puede apreciar como existen algunas palabras con errores ortográficos. El modelo debería ser entrenado con un conjunto de productos disponibles, y darse cuenta de que, por ejemplo: '***bateiras***' hace referencia al producto '***batería***'.
De igual manera, ocurriría lo mismo con el resto de productos de esta solicitud:

- leids ==> LED (el usuario trató de haber escrito 'leds').
- actavox ==> altavoz
- transnistores ==> transistor
- fulsilbes ==> fusibles
- interrutroes ==> interruptor

La lista con el nombre de los productos disponibles es limitada en este caso:

```
 etiquetas = ['resistencia',
              'capacitorceramico',
              'capacitorelectrolitico',
              'altavoz',
              'led',
              'semiconductor',
              'interruptor',
              'capacitor',
              'potenciometro',
              'varistor',
              'termistor',
              'fuentealimentacion',
              'triac',
              'tiristor',
              'diodozener',
              'cristalcuarzo',
              'ldr',
              'transistor',
              'fusible',
              'selector',
              'pulsadorna',
              'pulsadornc',
              'motor',
              'ohmimetro',
              'voltimetro',
              'amperimetro',
              'rele',
              'lamparaneon',
              'microchip',
              'ram',
              'lentecamara',
              'ventilador',
              'bateria',
              'tarjetared',
              'discoduro']
```

Tengo un csv que cuenta con estos mismos nombres, pero bien escritos. La lista anterior los muestra procesados (sin mayúsculas, sin espacios, sin signos de puntuación). Hago encapié aquí en que algunos nombres aparecen juntos, pero realmente el usuario los pondría separados:   '*tarjetared*' ==> '*tarjeta red*'; '**lamparaneon**' ==> '*lampara neon*'.

---

**IMPLEMENTACION ACTUAL** ----------------------------------

La funcionalidad que tengo ahora implementada funciona medianamente bien para este caso, pero me gustaría escalarlo a un sistema donde, fácilmente, podrían haber miles de productos disponibles.

Lo primero que hago es crear un hashmap con los nombres de los productos, y les asigno un valor numérico a cada uno, a modo de índice.

```
dictVocab = {}
contador = 1
for nombre in etiquetas:
    dictVocab[nombre] = contador
    contador +=1
    
else:
    print(dictVocab)
```

Esta última instrucción imprimiría algo como esto:

```
{'resistencia': 1, 'capacitorceramico': 2, 'capacitorelectrolitico': 3, 'altavoz': 4, 'led': 5, 'semiconductor': 6, 'interruptor': 7, 'capacitor': 8, 'potenciometro': 9, 'varistor': 10, 'termistor': 11, 'fuentealimentacion': 12, 'triac': 13, 'tiristor': 14, 'diodozener': 15, 'cristalcuarzo': 16, 'ldr': 17, 'transistor': 18, 'fusible': 19, 'selector': 20, 'pulsadorna': 21, 'pulsadornc': 22, 'motor': 23, 'ohmimetro': 24, 'voltimetro': 25, 'amperimetro': 26, 'rele': 27, 'lamparaneon': 28, 'microchip': 29, 'ram': 30, 'lentecamara': 31, 'ventilador': 32, 'bateria': 33, 'tarjetared': 34, 'discoduro': 35}
```

Hago exactamente lo mismo con otra lista que contiene los nombres de los productos en plural (e.g.: 'altavoz' pasaría a ser 'altavoces' en esta nueva lista), y creo otro diccionario con la misma lógica aplicada al anterior.

Por último, creo otro hashmap que me permita obtener las unidades que ha pedido el cliente para cada producto en su solicitud. Este lo creo de la siguiente manera:

```
listaUnidades = [item for item in range(1,1001)]

dictUnidades = {}

contador = 0
for numero in listaUnidades:
    dictUnidades[str(numero)] = listaUnidades[contador]
    contador +=1
```

Este hashmap tendría la siguiente estructura como pares clave-valor:

```
dictUnidades = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3 ...}
```

Esto lo hago porque se supone que el usuario escribe en formato numérico cuantas unidades quiere para un producto (*"Necesito que me envieis 2 bateiras"*), y al procesar el texto, 2 queda reflejado como string, por lo que uso el hashmap para obtener su valor numérico.

---

**CODIGO FUNCIONALIDAD** ----------------------------------------

El código de la funcionalidad sería el siguiente:

```
import string
import difflib


solicitud = """Buenas! Necesito que me envieis 2 bateiras. 
               Por otro lado, ultimanente echamos en falta algunas unidades de leids, unas 3.
               También estaría bien 1 actavox. Gracias!
               
               Se me olvidaba añadir los siguientes productos: 
                 - Me han pedido que incluya en la compra 4 transnistores.
                 - Estamos bajos en stock de fulsilbes, por lo que no nos vendría mal 10 unidades.
                 - A partir de dentro de unas cuantas semanas, preveemos una maoyr venta de interrutroes."""

texto = solicitud.lower()
texto = texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

texto = texto.split()
dictPalabras = {}

#print(texto)




objetosNombrados = []
unidadesPedidas = []

for palabra in texto:
    if palabra not in dictVocab.keys():
        dictPalabras[palabra] = 0
    elif palabra in dictVocab.keys():
        dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocab[palabra]
    elif palabra in dictVocabPlural.keys():
        dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocabPlural[palabra]

else:
    for item in dictPalabras.keys():
        if dictPalabras[item] != 0:
            objetosNombrados.append(item)
            
for palabra in dictPalabras.keys():
    if dictPalabras[palabra] == 0:
        if palabra in dictUnidades:
            print(palabra)
            unidadesPedidas.append(dictUnidades[palabra])
            
        if palabra not in dictVocab.keys():
            mejor_coincidencia = difflib.get_close_matches(palabra, dictVocab.keys(), n=1, cutoff=0.7)
            if mejor_coincidencia:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocab[mejor_coincidencia[0]]
                objetosNombrados.append(mejor_coincidencia[0])
            else:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = 0
        elif palabra not in dictVocabPlural.keys():
            mejor_coincidencia = difflib.get_close_matches(palabra, dictVocabPlural.keys(), n=1, cutoff=0.7)
            if mejor_coincidencia:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocabPlural[mejor_coincidencia[0]]
                objetosNombrados.append(mejor_coincidencia[0])
            else:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = 0
        else:
            try:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocab[palabra]
            except:
                dictPalabras[palabra] = dictVocabPlural[palabra]
            
            

print(unidadesPedidas)
print(objetosNombrados)
```

El resultado de imprimir 'unidadesPedidas' y 'objetosNombrados' por pantalla, es el siguiente:

```
unidadesPedidas ==> [2, 3, 1, 4, 10]
objetosNombrados ==> ['bateria', 'led', 'altavoz', 'transistor', 'fusible', 'interruptor']
```

---

**LOGICA DEL CODIGO ACTUAL** ----------------------------------

Se preprocesa el texto de la solicitud (convirtiendo el texto a minusculas y eliminando caracteres especiales), y se crea un lista con todas las palabras del texto.

Acto seguido, se define un hashmap que contendrá:

- Como clave, siempre un nombre para un producto.
- Como valor para esa clave --> 0 si la palabra no se encuentra en los diccionarios definidos antes; valor de la clave en el diccionario anterior, si si se encuentra.

Esto se hace por que *es posible que el usuario haya escrito bien el nombre de un producto en su solicitud*, por lo que se añadiría al diccionario --> 'resistencia': 1 (1 es el valor que se definió en el diccionario anterior).

Se recorre cada clave del diccionario que tenga como valor 0, y se hace uso del método ***get_close_matches()*** de la librería '**difflib**' para poder hallar el número de cambios necesario en cada palabra para que se convierta en alguna del diccionario definido como vocabulario. Si este número de cambios se encuentra por debajo de cierto umbral (0.7), se añade el nombre 'real' del producto a la lista de productos encontradas.

Esto plantea una serie de situaciones:

- Permite que, en el caso de haber escrito 'bateiras' en lugar de 'baterias', el programa sea capaz de detectar que se ha querido escribir 'baterias', añadiendo así la palabra a la lista.
- Es posible se haya escrito mal una palabra, y el programa no llegue a detectar que se trata de una de estos productos del vocabulario inicial.
- Es posible también que, al escribir una palabra como 'montar', el programa detecte que se quería escribir 'motor', y no es cierto.
- El programa actual supone que las unidades pedidas y el nombre del producto van a la par. Es decir, si la lista unidadesPedidas es [1,2,3], y productosPedidos es ['resistencia', 'led', 'transistor'], se aplicaría cada unidad a su producto correspondiente. Sin embargo, imagino que esto podría llegar a variar, o no ser lo más eficiente en un caso real.

Lo que me gustaría sería aplicar esta misma lógica en un modelo, que me permita expandir esta funcionalidad a sistemas con miles de productos (si se ejecutase un bucle for con miles de iteraciones, un gran número de veces al día, el sistema perdería mucha eficiencia).

No conozco mucho de modelo de NLP, y tampoco he encontrado alguno que me sirva para poder obtener el resultado que busco.
Agradezco mucho vuestro tiempo.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: No se de ias, pero si lo que te importa es la velocidad, te recomiendo [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), que tiene métodos implementados en c y por lo tanto es más rapido, pero que trabaja en memoria (si tu csv es grande, va a acabarse la memoria).  O mejor, y lo habitual, usa una base de datos. Sin embargo, no importa si tu modelo fue creado por el propio openai, al fin y al cabo, es posible aun que de falsos positivos y un humano deba revisar de todas formas. Al menos, por ahora.

Comment: Buenas Dante! En un principio, voy a seguir buscando información acerca de algún modelo de ML. Pero tendré en cuenta tu comentario en caso de no lograr el resultado que busco, igual acabo insertando y obteniendo los datos desde una BBDD. ¡Muchas gracias!